# Receiving data from a FormPanel in GWT

Tags: html, forms, gwt, http-post, formpanel

I have a FormPanel in GWT that should send a TextBox input to a new page (newPage.html). Below is my code. How do I receive this input in newPage.html, so that I can work with it from the associate newPage.java class? Thanks

```
final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

TextBox userid = new TextBox();
userid.setName("userid");
form.add(userid);

form.add(new Button("Submit", new ClickListener()
{    
    public void onClick(Widget sender)
    {
        form.submit();
    }
}));

form.setAction("newPage.html");
RootPanel.get("demo").add(form);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is POST variables from one gwt-page using a formpanel to another gwt-page to process these POST results you can not, simply because gwt-pages are coded with java but in the end they are translated into javascript and javascript alone can not access POST variables.

You need to define a backend that can process your form in your form.setAction() method that should execute on the server-side and produce a valid html/text response. To get these results produced by your backend you need to add a FormHandler to your FormPanel. There is an example showing how to do that on [javadocs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html#). Then evaluating these results you can redirect accordingly.

If you want to handle what you send with a java class meaning you have a java backend, why not use [GWT-RPC](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html)?